# Django not using correct Python instance from within virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv for developing in Django but Django is not using the correct instance of Python.  Here's what I've found out:

1. `C:\Python27` is not in my path.  If I run `python` from a command prompt it says it's not recognized
2. When I start up the virtualenv, run python and check `sys.executable` it does point to the virtualenv's instance of python and `sys.path` is also pointing to the correct place
3. When I run `manage.py shell` from within the virtualenv and check the `sys.executable` and `sys.path` they are both pointing to the `C:\python27` installation

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running `./manage.py shell` or `python manage.py shell`? It can make a difference.

Using the `./` version uses the shebang line for the interpreter and normally results in using the system-level interpreter. As you've seen yourself, running `python` uses the virtualenv's version, so `python manage.py shell` should as well.